# Fixing JSON::ParserError: 416: unexpected token at '{' without using EVAL

Tags: json, ruby

I'm trying to parse a `Hash` that is represented as a `String`, take this example:

```
arr = "[{\"key\"=>\"VALUE\"}, {\"key\"=>\"VAlUE\"}]"

JSON.parse arr

=> JSON::ParserError: 416: unexpected token at '{"key"=>"VALUE"}, {"key"=>"VALUE"}]'
```

Ok, that's unfortunate and I realize that it's not JSON I'm trying to parse. But I can do this:

```
arr = "[{\"key\"=>\"VALUE\"}, {\"key\"=>\"VALUE\"}]"

eval(arr)

=> [{"key"=>"VALUE"}, {"key"=>"VALUE"}]
```

That's cool but I don't want to use EVAL due to the security risk.

How can I achieve the same result that EVAL gets me but without using it?

Comment: How does the string come into existence? Can't you change the output so that a proper JSON string is exported?

Comment: What about `JSON.parse(arr.gsub("=>", ":"))`? (within begin/rescue block for reasonable fallback)

Comment: ^ assuming that `=>` will not be in the key itself, and the key is a string. Since it's currently plain Ruby `{1=>"value"}` would also be allowed. Here the `1` should be quoted first since JSON allows only string keys. The same with symbols or other types of keys.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Because of that, this is not an answer but a comment :) Obviously, you cannot parse as json something that is not a json. So there are two options: you either convert it to a valid json somehow, or deserialize in some other way. Obviously, there is no easy way to convert _arbitrary_ Ruby data structure, serialized to string, into a valid json. But in the cases when some a priori assumptions can be made in advance, it might make sense (with the reasonable fallback).